# need help understanding a code example from the AWS Amazon Cognito developer guide regarding developer provided authentication method

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, identity, amazon-cognito

In [this page from the Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html#getting-a-token-server-side), there is a code sample which says:

```
idRequest.setIdentityId("14232"); <--- this line here is the line of concern
# please use Control/Command+F to find this line
```

The broader code view for your clearer context is as follows:

```
// Create a new request to retrieve the token for your end user
GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest idRequest =
  new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest();
idRequest.setIdentityPoolId("YOUR_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID");
idRequest.setIdentityId("14232");
```

Here we are getting ready to establish the identity of a new user for the first time in Amazon Cognito Client.

Now, I am trying to understand why are we calling `setIdentityId()` here whereas (at this point of the code) we still don't have any identity provisioned for us by Cognito yet? What are we supposed to ***set*** the ***IdentityId*** with? Why is `"14232"` used here?

In a supporting Xamarin SDK documentation for [Amazon Cognito API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentity/MCognitoIdentityCognitoIdentityGetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityGetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest.html), it says

> When you want to create a new identity, the IdentityId should be null. When you want to associate a new login with an existing authenticated/unauthenticated identity, you can do so by providing the existing IdentityId.

I am confused that, if the documentation is saying that "***the identityId should be null***" when we are trying to create a new identity, then why did the official code sample in the developer guide use ***14232*** instead of ***null***?

Trying to figure out this new Cognito thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, null identity id should be passed when there is no identity id. Typically when you get the identity id, you will pass it back the the client, client will pass the same identity id which you will use to populate in GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems to me that, you make a `idRequest` with an identity ID. If you want to create a new identity, you can pass it `null`. When you associate this with existing one, that's the time you need to pass the existing `identityId`[which is done in this code]. And in response you get the `identityId` back, which is captured again in the last lines of code just to validate that the request was successful.

Here's a detailed explanation on the parameters of the request- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html

Comment: The example is not talking about associating with existing one. It's talking about creating a new one. Could this be a code sample bug?